# Unicode triangle U+25BA ► appears jagged?

Tags: css, unicode, antialiasing

► Is there a way to apply anti-aliasing/smoothing to the edges of this unicode triangle?

Comment: if you're using a filter in IE then this is not surprising.  Otherwise, `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` will help in chrome/safari

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rgSB2/

Answer (score 1):

Based on my testing it looks like the best bet is to use `text-shadow`, depending on which direction the triangle is pointing:

```
text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .45); // To the right
text-shadow: -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .45); // To the left
```

Each browser seems to handle exactly how this turns out a little differently.  In Firefox it's barely noticeable, in Safari it looks fantastic.

I gathered all the different techniques for trying to smooth web fonts into one place on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XdP6x/

[image: Example of Unicode Triangle with various CSS faux-anti-aliasing techniques.]

While I think the `text-stroke` option in Webkit looks slightly better than `text-shadow`, it wasn't possible to easily combine both techniques to get better results than `text-shadow` alone.

Font-smoothing did nothing and blurring looked hideous.  I also tried `transform:rotate(360deg);` to no effect.

I also found [various unicode triangles](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/geometric_shapes.html) other than 25BA.  Not all devices and browsers seem to support 25C0 and 25B6, I suggest using 25BA and 25C4.

--

Alternatively try using an SVG as a CSS background: http://jsfiddle.net/z6hw281a/